# Poker in the Star Trek universe: What are the stakes?

Tags: star-trek

Obviously, when gambling with Ferengi or other aliens, the stakes are usually latinum. But on the Enterprise (or in Federation space in general), are they still playing for latinum, or are they betting chores (as seen in Firefly) or maybe holodeck time or replicator credits? I did a quick check on [Memory Alpha](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Poker), but it's not really spelled out what the poker players on the Enterprise-D are betting. I'm fairly sure they're not just playing for fun.

I'm asking about Star Trek in general, not just the poker games we see on *TNG*.

Comment: **<comments removed>** Take the tangential discussion on the nature of poker to chat, please.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

### In-Universe :

Since the Federation doesn't *do* [money](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Memory_Alpha:AOL_chats/Ronald_D._Moore/ron009.txt), the wagers are essentially meaningless. Play seems to be for the bragging rights as to who won or lost, the fun element of the game and the psychological focus on [strategic thinking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_games_in_Star_Trek#Games_of_strategy_and_logic).

The exception to this in TNG is from the episode [Quality of Life](http://www.st-minutiae.com/academy/literature329/235.txt) where Beverley Crusher taunts Will Riker into wagering his beard on the final outcome:

> **BEVERLY :** Okay... what do you say we up the stakes a little? If I win
> this hand... you all shave off your beards [and] if one of you wins --
> I become a brunette. Are we on?
>
> **GEORDI :** We'll take that bet.
>
> <sup><sub>*n.b. script edited for brevity*</sub></sup>

And in the Voyager episode [Collective](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/614.htm) :

> **NEELIX:** *I don't know what you're talking about. I've, I've, this is
> the first time I've played. What is it called?*
>
> **ALL:** *Poker*.
>
> **PARIS:** *Look, why don't we make things a little more interesting.
> **Forget the chips. Let's bet on tomorrow's work detail,** all right?
> Whoever wins this hand gets the morning off.*
>
> **CHAKOTAY:** *I'm in.*

Mirroring Crusher in TNG, Paris says to forget the chips (which obviously have no worth) and offers a physical wager instead.

---

### Out of universe

It's pretty clear that the actors and writers had no idea either. Despite the script constantly referencing Gene Roddenberry's assertion that the Federation is a 'post-scarcity' society with no money, the actress playing Deanna Troi (Marina Sirtis) [clearly felt differently](http://www.bbc.co.uk/cult/st/interviews/sirtis/page29.shtml):

> Generally, with most
> beings, I could just sense what they were feeling, so I was empathic.
>
> Why I was in the poker game, I will never know, because poker's about
> sensing when people are bluffing, and **there I was in a poker game
> every week. I don't think you ever actually saw me win bundles of
> money but I'm sure, off screen, at some point that was what I did.**

as did showrunner [Ronald D. Moore](http://trekmovie.com/2008/06/12/exclusive-interview-ron-moore-on-breaking-out-of-the-box/):

> It is a strange platitude
> that we used on the show, **the need for money was gone and everything
> was about bettering yourself.** It was no longer about any kind of
> material gain or personal gain, everyone was just trying to be a
> better person So none of us could understand what that mean or how
> that society functioned. It all seemed very vague. None of the writers
> took it seriously. We all kind of laughed about it and joked about it.
> **We all had to pay homage to it because that was something that was
> built into the structure of the show.** At every opportunity we tried to
> sneak in ways. **How do you play poker if you don’t have currency? Again
> The Original Series had credits and currency and we never understood
> why they could do all these great things and we couldn’t. It was very
> odd.**

Comment: There's also the line from "Lower Decks" to the effect of, "I just cleaned out some junior officers and thought I'd do the same up here," but there's no clear indication of what he cleaned them out *of* (except maybe their pride).

Comment: That's one of the things that makes me think they're betting something tangible, not just "bragging rights". Also, I just can't see Riker gambling for fun - there has to be something on the line.

Comment: Many phrases we used in the past linger on in current usage even though their original meaning is no longer valid - "cleaning out" the junior officers could simply mean he took all the chips.

Comment: Your answer is dead-on (as always), at least regarding in TNG. In VOY, however, we see Paris run a gambling thing, where people can bet their replicator rations and (I believe) duty time. Until Janeway and Chakotey close it down. [Disclaimer: Comment because not double-checked on M.A., ymmv]

Comment: @bitmask - I've deliberately excluded Voyager and TOS because the questions was about Enterprise-D. In Voyager, they basically reinvented money because they were no longer a post-scarcity society and in TOS the crew still used credits for external activities.

Comment: @JoeL.: According to [Anthony Holden (a.k.a. "London Tony")](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthony_Holden#Poker), there are two things one must always keep in mind while playing poker; first, the money isn't important, it's just a way of keeping score, and second, the money is extremely important, that's the rent you're playing with. I choose to believe that this will be true as long as poker remains a game worth playing.

Comment: @Richard: I never said the question was limited to TNG. That was an edit by someone else, which I'm changing now.

Comment: @JoeL. - That would make it a lot broader but not necessarily better

Comment: @Richard: My original intent was to ask about gambling stakes within the supposedly post-currency economic structure of Starfleet. Preferably without sounding like an economist or a lawyer.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a definitive canon answer. In-universe, it seems like humans treat the greedy/acquisitive side of our nature much the same way Vulcans treat their emotions - arrogant pride layered on top of denial and over-compensation. But there's a core of ugly truth: the knowledge that "this will destroy us if we let it".

Comment: I like to think that during filming of that scene in *A Quality of Life*, Riker fixed Beverly with a wicked stare and said “Collar and cuffs, Bev.”

Comment: As a curiosity, who won that bet on Riker's beard?

Comment: @BogdanAlexandru: The hand was never finished. Senior officers were called in by Captain Picard. Beverly was pretty flustered about it, as she actually had a decent hand.

Comment: They are playing with chips which have some sort of denomination in some sort of unit, whether explicitly spoken in dialog or not ("credits", perhaps). That they have value in being won or lost, and if they have any value in exchange for labor or some tangible commodity makes those units a currency, post-scarcity or not.

Comment: @AnthonyX - Is monopoly money a currency then? It's pretty clear that the winner is the person with the most 'chips' but the chips don't mean anything other than as a score-keeping mechanism

Comment: @Valorum As soon as you use it as a medium of exchange for goods or services, it becomes a currency, such as if someone accepted monopoly money in exchange for household chores. Yes, I've played texas hold'em where everyone is issued something like $50,000 in chips and hands are played until one player has them all - it can be just a way of keeping score. But if those chips are exchanged for something of value outside the game, it's money, not points.

Comment: @AnthonyX - Indeed. So in this case the chips are meaningless. It's not until Beverly Crusher gets into a pissing contest with Riker that the stakes become real. And even then, they stop using the chips and start betting on dares.

Answer (score 15):

Pride, favors, but mostly as fun or a mental/social exercise.  We see when Picard joins the game in "All Good Things" pt2 they just hand him a stack of chips with no discussion of buy in.  There also seems to be cross pollination of chips between games on the ship during "The Lower Decks" s7e15 when Ben takes his winnings from the Ensigns game to the Command Staff game.  It is implied that such "officers" games are common on Starfleet Vessels as Riker used it as a way to access the command staff socially on the "USS Potemkin".  We also have references of "favors" owed by other Federation Officers earned during card games peppered throughout the show.  Items like Romulan Ale, minor favors (covering shifts or doing undesirable duties), information, or favorable crew allotments are all things that Starfleet Officers will play for, including the shaving of beards (s6e09).

We can assume there is some sort of Starfleet Regulation on gambling it's stakes, as gambling for too high stakes or with the wrong people can create security risks or threats to crew cohesion.  Within those limits groups of crew self organize pickup games or potentially shipwide competitions. It seems that on the Enterprise-D Riker is the main instigator of Poker (five card stud) and probably indirectly influences how the crew plays it and their standards for rules and fairness.

Answer (score 2):

Victory Points.

Imagine you have a box on your desk that you can punch some buttons, pick from a menu, give voice commands; that can convert energy into matter. You can ask for a gold ingot, steak fajitas, a 16 oz. mojito, a stack of silver dollars, gold Krugerrands, whatever you want.

So what can you do with those silver dollars? You *could* buy something, but anyone else with a similar box isn't going to find your silver dollars compelling because they could just get some from their box.

Consider other games, like Ticket to Ride. You don't (usually) play this for money. The goal is to score the most points.

So the chips in poker merely represent your score for the game.

Even though Ticket to Ride is not a 'gambling' game you could still play it for prizes (money, favors, challenges [beards vs. hair coloring]).

Comment: I don't understand why this answer was at -1.  It is essentially correct, even if it is less well-referenced than the answers above.

Comment: @jules - Given the very strong body of canon work related to star trek, unreferenced "I think..." answers will always attract down votes.