# In the absence of money, what motivated the crew of the TNG Enterprise to play poker?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, money

Playing poker with and without money is very different. With money bets, people can get scared off when the bets get big and that is when a 'poker face' matters. Without money bets, there is little emotion involved.

In the Star Trek world, money does not exist, taking the fun and excitement away from poker. **So why is poker still a favourite game among Star Trek TNG crew despite [the lack of monetary stakes](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/66636/poker-in-the-star-trek-universe-what-are-the-stakes?noredirect=1&lq=1)?**

Comment: Skill? Socializing? Learning their companions quirks and tells?

Comment: "*money does not exist. This takes the fun and excitement away from poker.*" - citation needed.

Comment: @Rand al'Thor, I thought it is common sense. Casino games are meaningless if money stakes are absent. Can Las Vegas still attract customers if the casino games are not played with money on the line?

Comment: May I ask why the high number of negative votes? What is wrong with the question? I would like to know what is wrong before deleting the question. Thanks.

Comment: @user486818 I downvoted because I think the question is based on a false premise. It's perfectly possible to enjoy card games without gambling. Personally, I've never gambled but have still enjoyed playing various card games which are often played with money stakes.

Comment: @Rand al'Thor, thanks for your feedback. Upvoted your comment. I guess the premise is false for some people, true for some people.

Comment: @Rand al'Thor, For most card games, I would agree with you. For Poker, I disagree. The poker face edge cannot be put into advantage when money is not at stake.

Comment: @user486818 Why can't it?  The goal is to get the most chips, so it's totally possible to win/lose.

Comment: I don't think this is a dupe. The other question focuses purely on the stakes at stake, this question is more about why they'd choose that game in particular (e.g. over tiddlywinks, for example).

Comment: @user486818 - I've never understood how the place stays in business, period.

Comment: Have they never played for Latinum?

Comment: Poker without money is still extremely interesting. For example, most of the poker you see on television is *not* for money, in the sense that the chips have a value. You can't save your money by betting low in a poker tournament.

Comment: This really belongs on boardgames.SE. Every single poker game I've played has been friendly, with no stakes. I'd wager (nothing actually, this is the Internet after all) that most poker games played in general are without stakes. So why is it so hard to imagine that would be the case on Star Trek too? Nothing science-fictional is required to explain something so perfectly ordinary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would appear that the crew primarily enjoy the *tactical* elements of the game, especially bluff, counterbluff and confrontation.

**Riker uses the game to hone his negotiation skills.**

> **PICARD:** *Well, I'm the designated host. It would be a most awkward transition. You're the next likely choice. And Mister Mendoza will
> certainly agree. He's quite impressed by your natural instincts.*
>
> **RIKER:** *Excuse me, sir, but those weren't natural instincts. Those were poker instincts. A card game doesn't exactly prepare me for
> this.*
>
> **PICARD:** *Yes, the stakes are higher. But then, isn't that when the game gets interesting, Commander?*
>
> <sub><sup>[TNG: The Price](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/156.htm)</sup></sub>

**Riker uses the game to interact with (and to assess) his junior officers.**

> **SHELBY:** *I've only got two pair, Commander. But I've got to see that blind card. I'll call.*
>
> [She puts in her chips. Riker blinks... looks down at his card... turns
> it over. It busts his straight flush. He's bluffing. Reactions. Wesley
> groans, hangs his head.]
>
> **GEORDI:** (delighted) *You got him!*
>
> [**Riker and Shelby's eyes meet.** She collects the winnings.]
>
> <sub><sup>[TNG: The Best of Both Worlds, Part I - Original Script](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/174.txt)</sup></sub>

**Data, in particular gets a lot from the game, learning about how humans interact in *social situations***

> **DATA:** ***When I play poker with my shipmates, it often appears to be a useful forum for exploring the different facets of humanity.** I was curious to see how three of history's greatest minds would interact in this setting. So far, it has proved most illuminating.*
>
> <sub><sup>[TNG: Legacy](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/180.htm)</sup></sub>

**As well as helping him to assess aspects of humanity in relation to how humans calculate risk and exposure, which in turn has improved his tactical skills**

> **DATA:** *In the game of poker, there is a moment when a player must decide if an opponent is being deceptive or actually holds a winning
> hand. This decision is based not only on the odds, but also on an
> appraisal of the man. Is he bluffing or does he have the cards?*
>
> <sub><sup>[TNG: Data's Day](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/185.htm)</sup></sub>

---

Interestingly, on at least one occasion the ability to play poker proves advantageous when the crew is sent back in time with limited resources. Data's gambling skills allow him to earn sufficient money to build a scanner out of contemporary parts in [TNG: Time's Arrow.](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/226.htm)

Comment: +1 Tactical element. The only *stakes* I recall was Riker shaving his beard vs Beverly dying her hair. But the game was interupted by a red alert or whatever.